# Trouble with keyup in jQuery

Tags: jquery, onkeyup

Maybe noobie question about the keyup function, if the document is ready the div with id "testdiv" is empty that should not be. I want the testdiv empty if you really keyup. I have made a tiny script like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){  
        $('#test:input').keyup(function () {
            $('#testdiv').empty();              
        }).keyup(); 
    });
</script>
<input type="textfield" id="test" value="test123"/>
<div id="testdiv">Test</div>
```

Do I have to bind it?  Sorry for this beginner question.

Regards,

Frank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#test:input').keyup(function () {
    $('#testdiv').empty();              
}).keyup();
```

This says "bind a keyup handler, then immediately trigger it". The second `keyup` call triggers the handler.  If you don't want it fired immediately, remove it:

```
$('#test:input').keyup(function () {
    $('#testdiv').empty();              
});
```

Comment: Thanks, yea stupid of me immediately triggered it sorry for this dumb question ;)

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
}).keyup();
```

...Immediately executes the function you defined for keyup. You don't want that.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('#test:input').keyup(function () {
        $('#testdiv').empty();              
    });
});
```